# Message: file size limit exceeded when doing scp command on macOS Big Sur Version 11.6

Tags: linux, bash, macos, terminal, scp

I am trying to fetch a dump file from one of my Ubuntu servers. The dump file is stored in .gzip format and his size is about 3GB. And then when I execute a scp command in macOS Big Sur Version 11.6 the download begins normally. After that when about 95MB has bin downloaded the command stops with this message.

```
sh: file size limit exceeded  scp -P1021  /Users/andrej/Desktop
```

even though I have enough space on my machine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AIzH.png)

Also the settings for filesize limit is set to unlimitted on my laptop here is the output of the launchctl limit command from my terminal and ulimit -a.

```
 % launchctl limit
    cpu         unlimited      unlimited      
    filesize    unlimited      unlimited      
    data        unlimited      unlimited      
    stack       8388608        67104768       
    core        0              unlimited      
    rss         unlimited      unlimited      
    memlock     unlimited      unlimited      
    maxproc     2784           4176           
    maxfiles    64000          524288
```

The output of ulimit -a

```
% ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              200000
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-u: processes                       2042
-n: file descriptors                65536
```

Maybe someone has encountered a similar problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and also show the output of `ulimit -a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not noticed that I had a configuration set to 200000 for the filesize when I run the ulimit -a command. The issue was resolved after setting this value to unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

try using rsync utility it's well suited with large files